# How do you configure BIND to forward reverse DNS queries to another DNS server?

Tags: bind, forwarding, reverse-dns

I've got 2 domains in my environment. One of them is an active directory domain for 'myproductionlab.local' at 10.60.0.0/16 
Then I have a debian box running bind9 for a domain, 'mytestlab.local'
I have added an entry into my named.conf.local:

```
zone "60.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type forward;
        forwarders {
                10.60.10.5;
                10.60.10.7;
                10.60.10.9;

        };
};
zone "myproductionlab.local" {
        type forward;
        forwarders {
                10.60.10.5;
                10.60.10.7;
                10.60.10.9;

        };
};
```

the debian box is configured to have 127.0.0.1 for DNS resolution and there are no forwarders globally configured.

name resolution resolves just fine:

```
nslookup mymachine.myproductionlab.local  
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mymachine.myproductionlab.local
Address: 10.60.10.200
```

and from the query log:

```
client 127.0.0.1#36076 (mymachine.myproductinlab.local): query: mymachine.myproductionlab.local IN A + (127.0.0.1)
```

but reverse DNS isn't forwarded:

```
nslookup 10.60.10.200
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53
** server can't find 200.10.60.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

and from query log:

```
client 127.0.0.1#40295 (200.10.60.10.in-addr.arpa): query: 200.10.60.10.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (127.0.0.1)
```

I've tried a bunch of zone variations:

```
zone "60.10.in-addr.arpa" {
zone "10.60.10.in-addr.arpa" {
zone "200.10.60.10.in-addr.arpa" {
```

I've also tried to tcpdump and 0 packets are captured for nslookup 10.60.10.200 but packets are captured for the name.

when I manually specify the DNS server in nslookup it also works fine:

```
nslookup 10.60.10.200 10.60.10.5
Server:     10.60.10.5
Address:    10.60.10.5#53
200.10.60.10.in-addr.arpa   name = mymachine.myproductionlab.local.
```

Comment: I'll assume you reloaded the zone after your changes and did a namedconf check

Comment: Yes, I've reloaded each time and named-checkconf on all the configs reports no errors.

Comment: what's the output of `dig -x 10.60 10.200`

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I didn't use dig to troubleshoot until you mentioned. Post the suggestion as an answer and I can accept it as correct for you

Comment: so your rdns works, just an issue with nslookup

Comment: oh I just see it, lol woops

Comment: @spezticle Please post the solution as an answer (and accept it) instead of editing it into the question. (The site will not know that your question has been answered otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nslookup isn't very helpful, what's the output of `dig -x 10.60 10.200`

which showed your default private ranges were enabled and catching your requests as authority.

remove or edit them to be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

The output of DIG led me to discover the issue

```
dig -x 10.60.10.200

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u6-Debian <<>> -x 10.60.10.200
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 26824
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;200.10.60.10.in-addr.arpa. IN  PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
10.in-addr.arpa.    86400   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. 1 604800     86400 2419200 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 21 13:46:50 CST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

10.in-addr.arpa. was defined in zones.rfc1918 which points to db.empty
In previous versions of bind zones.rfc1918 was not included by default and even still I have checked all the configs and nothing is telling bind to read that file so it must be read by default now on this version or it's configured somewhere else.

```
dpkg -l | grep bind
ii  bind9                                1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u6            amd64        Internet Domain Name Server
ii  bind9-host                           1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u6        amd64        Version of 'host' bundled with BIND 9.X
ii  bind9utils                           1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u6        amd64        Utilities for BIND
ii  libbind9-90                          1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u6        amd64        BIND9 Shared Library used by BIND
```

Comment: In the event that you are using SystemD resolved, you must specify the actual server that resolved is querying - check the output of resolvectl status | grep "Current DNS Server" to get this IP. Then, with dig: dig @127.0.0.1 -x 10.60.10.200 . The internal resolved process will never return an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anybody hits this… For recent versions of Bind9 (at least on Debian) it is not sufficient to disable the

```
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
```

statement because Bind9 then automatically creates them. Instead,

```
empty-zones-enable no;
```

is required in your options section (`named.conf.options`).

See https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00800/0/Automatic-empty-zones-including-RFC-1918-prefixes.html.