# Configuring Reverse DNS for an emulated DNS server hierarchy using BIND

Tags: linux-networking, bind, reverse-dns, emulation, hierarchy

I'm emulating a network using Kathara (similar to Netkit) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get reverse DNS to work across all three networks.

[This is the topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn276.jpg)

[And this is the DNS hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPEQk.jpg)

I did manage to get recursive lookup to work. When queried for a name not in its database, ns.as1.net would query nsroot, then go down the hierarchy, finally getting a response from the authoritative server. I did this by adding a db.root file with a record for nsroot's address and using it for zone "."

named.conf:

```
[...]
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};
[...]
```

db.root:

```
.                   IN  NS    ROOT-SERVER.
ROOT-SERVER.        IN  A     1.1.2.2
```

My question is: **How do I get it to work the same way for Reverse DNS?**

I only managed to get it to work locally by configuring `zone "3.3.in-addr.arpa"`  on `ns.as3.net`, but this way, it only works for the hosts that have ns.as3.net set as their resolver.

MTR in AS3:

```
                             My traceroute  [v0.93]
c2as3 (3.3.2.2)                                        2021-06-29T02:11:52+0000
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                       Packets               Pings
 Host                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. r33.as3.net (3.3.2.1)             0.0%    12    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.0
 2. r32.as3.net (3.3.1.13)            0.0%    12    0.1   0.2   0.1   0.3   0.0
 3. ns.as3.net (3.3.4.2)              0.0%    11    0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.0
```

MTR from AS2 to AS3:

```
                             My traceroute  [v0.93]
c1as2 (2.2.2.2)                                        2021-06-29T02:14:22+0000
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                       Packets               Pings
 Host                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 2.2.2.1 (2.2.2.1)                 0.0%     7    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.0
 2. 2.2.1.9 (2.2.1.9)                 0.0%     6    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
 3. 2.2.0.2 (2.2.0.2)                 0.0%     6    0.2   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.0
 4. 3.3.1.6 (3.3.1.6)                 0.0%     6    0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.0
 5. 3.3.4.2 (3.3.4.2)                 0.0%     6    0.2   0.2   0.2   0.3   0.0
```

I did think about adding every arpa zone in all nameservers, but I don't think it's the proper way to do it.

I would greatly appreciate any tips or help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, you need to simulate a `root hints` NS server, because how else would the `ns.as3.net` know where to find the NS server responsible for the zone records for `1.1.in-addr.arpa` and `2.2.in-addr.arpa`?

Same applies for the two other name servers.

**Disclaimer**

The following written from a cell phone, so I haven't being able to verify grammar is correct, but you will hopefully get the idea. :-)

The alternative is of course you add a zone entry on `ns.as3.net` like:

```
zone "1.1.in-addr.arpa" {
  type forward;
  forwarders { x.x.x.x; }
  forward only;
};

zone "2.2.in-addr.arpa" {
type forward;
  forwarders { y.y.y.y; }
  forward only;
};
```

Replace `x.x.x.x` and `y.y.y.y` with the ip-adresse of the respective nameserver for  `as1.net` and `as2.net`.

Similar entries need to be added to the other name servers, so all name servers knows where all zone records are located.

Comment: Does this Solve your Issue? https://serverfault.com/questions/833824/how-do-you-configure-bind-to-forward-reverse-dns-queries-to-another-dns-server?rq=1

Comment: Are you asking *me* or @rzv.th? I only suggest two ways out to get intended behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the forward method.